# Is it correct to use splice and push for (old) state array change? Or we need to use newArray with ( slice and spread)?

Tags: reactjs

Is it correct to use splice and push for (old) state array change? Or we need to use newArray with ( slice and spread) ?

How to work correct? and how to get senior level in React?

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutate-state-bad-y98j6) is an example of optimized (pure) components not rendering because state is mutated (in handleChange). If you change it to: `let temp = {...this.state.metadata};` making a shallow copy of metadata and then shallow mutate that copy then it works again. If you can mutate state and have you app working then it's just because you didn't optimize your app, when you or someone else optimizes your app things will break. Also there are lots of benefits having pure functions. Mutating shared state may get some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official document have mentioned about this clearly. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

> **Never mutate this.state directly**, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

So we need to create another one for changing the state.

Answer (score 1):

State is mutable but never do it directly. Instead of that, we can take help of `setState()` or If you are using Functional Component, React Hooks provides `useState()`. Its Better to use these two methods to change any state.